# Which mails got deleted

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In my application, i have downloaded all emails from [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) over a period of time for my mailbox. Now some emails were permanently deleted / purged in outlook, so I need to find out which emails got deleted.

Is there some direct way to find out which mails got deleted recently? Maximum 1000 entries can be returned in 1 api call. It would be really very inefficient to download all emails for the mailbox and then comparing what I have in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Now some emails were permanently deleted / purged in outlook, so I need to find out which emails got deleted.

If the items are still in the retention period for the mailbox then they should be available in the dumpster folders eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/messages
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/RecoverableItemsPurges/messages
```

see (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/recoverable-items-folder/recoverable-items-folder)

If the messages have been purged from the Mailbox (eg past the retained items period) they like anything else they are gone for good. If auditing is enabled you should be able to get from the audit logs what email where deleted but it doesn't track when they are purged by the MRM process.

> Is there some direct way to find out which mails got deleted recently? Maximum 1000 entries can be returned in 1 api call. It would be really very inefficient to download all emails for the mailbox and then comparing what I have in database.

Using the delta endpoints is what you would normally use in a sync process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http this will let you know what CRUD ops have happened on messages with a particular folder/mailbox.

Comment: Delta API is the one i was looking for.. But seems like changeType=deleted is not working.. only changeType=created is working ... Do you have any idea, if some setting is missing?

Comment: Thanks Glen.. I am able to get it working.. actually we have to get the @odata.deltaLink URL in subsequent calls, that will keep the changes tracked..

Comment: Is the `RecoverableItemsPurges` folder name documented anywhere in the Graph docs? There is a list of well-known folder names at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0, but it doesn't include `RecoverableItemsPurges`.

Comment: Not that I know of but this is more an oversight in the docs you can try creating an issue on github if you need official confirmation.